# Android application

Tags: android

I want to know basically the hint of the softkeybaord which is displayed while editing or typing something in textbox is actually where it is stored.I want to know the location and way to handle it through programming.

Comment: Hint? Do you mean the auto-complete view?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the "hint" that is displayed in an `EditText` input area is from a

```
<string name="hint_string">Hint text</string>
```

entry in the `values/strings.xml`resource.

Then to populate the "hint" in the `EditText` box you simply add this attribute to the layout .xml file:

```
<EditText>
    android:hint="@string/hint_string"
</EditText>
```

Further info found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#TextView_hint).